# Data not getting added to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and nodejs. I am trying to add some data to MongoDB but it's not getting updated in the database. Can someone help me figure out the issue? My code is as follows:

```
    for (i = 0; i < DataArray.length; i++) {
        try {
           const newDoc = new Document(DataArray[i]);
           newDoc.save()
                 .then(() => logger.info("Data Added !!"))
                 .catch((err) => {
                      logger.error(err);
                      logger.info("Something went wrong");
                 });
        }
    }
```

The DataArray is a list of documents that need to be added to MongoDB. I am trying to take each data and add it to db. Document is the reference to the particular collection in db.

Answer (score 1):

You are running `save` in for loop, do this instead:

```
await Promise.all(
    DataArray.map(async (data) => {
        const newDoc = new Document(data);

        await newDoc.save();            
        logger.info("Data Added !!")
       
        return data;
    })
);

const allDocuments = await Document.find();
console.log("allDocuments", allDocuments);
```

Comment: The code is working without any error and even shows the data added info but data is not reflecting in the db

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the correct DB?

Comment: Yes, I'm the connection URL is correct

Comment: Please try my updated answer once.

Comment: NOw that I have added const error = await newDoc.save().catch(error => error); its not responding once the code reaches there

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: no error either

Comment: I have reverted the code, it should work, please check your db after you see the `console.log('allDocuments')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237443/discussion-between-anjali-a-and-harshit-rastogi).

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDb Basic Flow is like this & Use **Async-Await** in your function.

Step 1: Define Schema in your file
exp.

```
const userSchema = require('your schema path here');
```

Step 2: Put Values in Schema Object
exp.

```
const user = new userSchema({username: 'darshanuraval', age: 23});
```

Step 3: Put this Save Function in Try Catch So that if any errors comes then we got that in catch.
exp.

```
try {
    await user.save();
    res.send("inserted data");
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: I am following the steps except await in the .save() part can that be the issue?

Comment: @AnjaliA `Await` and `.then()` does the same thing.

Comment: Ohh okayy! but its not working for me!

Comment: @AnjaliA yeah, you can use await or .then() as your requirement. I think you used save inside for loop so can you try with .map and fix that map with promise so it's work. because same issue faced me and at that time i'm used .map and promise that map function and inside map function i used await mongodb queries for update.

Comment: Could you pls update it in the answer

Comment: @AnjaliA I added new answer please check it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In other way Try this, Use Promise and Map function so it's works.

```
let obj = await Promise.all(DataArray.map(async function(mapData){
    let newDoc = new Document(mapData);
    await newDoc.save();
    return mapData;
}));
```

Comment: Could you reformat the code :/ not getting hold of it here mapData.dataValues.bidData = bidData;

Comment: Check I updated Code as per your question. :)

Comment: getting no response!

Comment: oops :( sorry...